# How to revert pixel colors back after changing them?

Tags: java, image, colors

I need to add tint to a picture and then revert the picture back to its original color. I am able to add tint but don't know how to revert the picture back to it's original colors.

I want to create a method where it resets the picture back to its original color.

#### Attempt

```
public void changeBlues(double param){
    Pixel[] pixelArray =  this.getPixels();
    Pixel pixel = null;
    int value = 0;
    int index = 0;
    
    if(param <= 0.0){
      System.out.println("Error! Parameter less than or equal to 0.0");
      return;
    }
    else if(param > 5.0){
      System.out.println("Error! Paramater is greater than five.");
      return;
    }
    
      
    
    //loop through all the pixels

    //get the current pixel
    while(index < (int)(pixelArray.length)){  
      if(param < 1.0){
        pixel = pixelArray[index];
        
        //get the value
        value = pixel.getBlue();
        
        // decrease the value by param
        value = (int)((value - (value * param)));
        
        // set he blue value of the current pixel to the new value
        pixel.setBlue(value);
        
        // increment the index
        index = index + 1;
      }
      
      pixel = pixelArray[index];
      
      //get the value
      value = pixel.getBlue();
      
      // decrease the value by param
      value = (int)((value + (value * param)));
      
      // set he blue value of the current pixel to the new value
      pixel.setBlue(value);
      
      // increment the index
      index = index + 1;
      
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You either need to maintain a copy of the original data or generate a delta so you know what was changed and how

Comment: How would I maintain a copy of the original data?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by MadProgrammer, you need to either maintain a copy of the original, or create a (bidirectional) delta for each change. The advantage of the later is, that you can revert to all stages of your editings, sort of like a history (CTRL + Z/Y in many programs under windows).

To do this, you need to create an object that stores the pixel change information and can be applied or reverted. Since you loop over all pixels, and practically almost all pixels will be affected, you could just store the entire image in the history. This depends on whether you will have operations in your program that change the image on a more limited basis, instead of making whole-picture-modifications.

@Edit:
Since you want to rotate between multiple different tinted pictures, aparrently, just genreate the three buffered pictures and rorate them.

Comment: There is a program that I must add code to. What the program does is ask for a picture from the user and then the picture chosen by the user gets tinted to the color of what I code. A second after it will go to another color that I coded. and then it will do it a third time. I thought I could increase certain pixels by a certain percentage and then decreasing them back the same percentage but I figured that won't work because when I decrease by a certain percent it will use the new value so it won't go back to the original value if that makes sense.

Comment: the reason I need to revert to the original color is because when I just have the code of the colors each time it runs though it just mixes the colors together so it doesn't tint the color I want it to tint.

Comment: You are correct, it wouldn't go back to original color. Though I still don't entirely understand the purpose, I suppose that you do something like a color rotation effect, much like a video. So then, just store the n (I believe 3) different pictures your want to tint to, and rotate them.